# Where occurs diamine oxidase in kidneys - in cells or in extracellular space?

Tags: enzymes

I would be interested in where the enzyme diamine oxidase in **kidneys** of human/animals mainly occurs? In cells or in extracellular space? A literature reference if available would be great. Thanks!